# MKReverseGeocoderInternal Memory leak

Tags: iphone

Code:

```
geoCoder =[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:UserLocation];
```

Where to release GeoCoder though I release in `dealloc` method? It give me memory leak...

Answer (score -1):

I have this code.
I made sure it was actually allocated before I tried to release it, I also set it to nil.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    if(address!=nil) {
        address = nil;
        [address release];
    }

    // releae the map delegate otherwise it will try and call our classes with no data.
    map.delegate = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I hope you release it before you set it to nil.

Comment: 1. You set address = nil and send release message to nil object? Why?


 address may be allocated. then deallocated. But after that address is not nil

Comment: Actually good point, I have looked at this answer on StackOverflow.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211018/objective-c-release-dealloc-and-the-self-reference

I think I should have it in the opposite order.
[address release]; address = nil;

The nil might not be needed but I don't think it is bad.
Thanks for the comments, I am still learning as well on this stuff. Cheers John.